# Excluding nulls from row_to_json() result in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql

I want to convert the rows of a record set to JSON, but not include any null entries that are just going to end up being undefined in JavaScript anyway. For example, suppose I have the table `testdata` with entries

```
id | prop1 (integer) | prop2 (text)
-------------------------------------
 1 |               42 | 'Answer'
 2 |             NULL | 'No prop one'
 3 |                0 | NULL
```

and then execute

```
SELECT row_to_json(testdata) FROM testdata
```

**What I get** is:

```
{"id":"1","prop1":"42","prop2":"Answer"}
{"id":"2","prop1":null,"prop2":"No prop one"}
{"id":"3","prop1":"0","prop2":null}
```

But instead, **what I want** is:

```
{"id":"1","prop1":"42","prop2":"Answer"}
{"id":"2","prop2":"No prop one"}
{"id":"3","prop1":"0"}
```

Is this possible? According to the [JSON functions documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) for PostgreSQL 9.3, there's only one extra option or parameter for `row_to_json`, but setting `pretty_bool=true` doesn't remove the nulls, so it seems as if the answer may be no. But this also seems as if it's a very obvious and useful function, so I'm hoping that somebody else has found something I've missed.

My end goal is to retrieve the records in JavaScript with a `GET` call to a PHP page. Am I better off building the JSON in PHP from a more standard recordset, instead of using PostgreSQL's JSON routines?

Comment: _but not include any null entries that are just going to end up being undefined in JavaScript anyway_ The property will be null not undefined. It will be undefined if you remove it from the object as you want to do.

Comment: I meant that I need them to be undefined, so they will end up being undefined in my particular JavaScript application -- it's just a question of where along the chain from PostgreSQL through PHP to JS that I manage to make that happen. Of course, that doesn't affect my question in any way...

Comment: Are you sure there is a gain in having the property undefined in instead of null? I don't see the point. Ask it to the JS experts.

Comment: I suppose you're right, there's probably not much difference... I hadn't thought about it much, because my goal is to not have the values there at all. My question here isn't about JavaScript, it's about PostgreSQL and how to generate JSON such that I don't have to send the missing values to the browser in the first place.

Answer (score 14):

Postgres 9.5 introduces [`json_strip_nulls`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) function, that seems to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like future versions of the function may have an 'ignore nulls' option - https://commitfest.postgresql.org/action/patch_view?id=1496

Comment: Sadly [this patch was pulled](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/commit/c8a026e4f15e2063cd7fe6cb9ffe44f2a81398bd) from the code - [see this discussion](http://postgresql.nabble.com/json-b-and-null-fields-td5820666.html).  Hopefully an alternative will make it in time for Postgres 9.5, though I can't see anything in the Postgres code at the moment.

Comment: Postgresql 9.5 (currently still in development) has the [json_strip_nulls](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/functions-json.html) function.